# Executing SSRS Reports From SSIS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to execute a SSRS reports from SSIS on periodic schedule.

Saw a solution here :

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3475/execute-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-from-integration-services-package/

But is there any other option in SSIS without using Script Task ? I don't quite understand the script and concern there could be some support issue for me.

Database : SQL Server 2008R2 Standard Edition

Any ideas ? Thanks very much ...

Comment: Why you don't generate the report in Excel from SSRS and share the file to a folder? You can do this using SSRS Subscriptions (SSIS is not required). Use SSIS to process the Excel file or send it in different ways not provided by SSRS .

Comment: I need the PDF format that has been approved and accepted by all users

Comment: Another alternative is to set a flag in SSIS and then run the SSRS from SQL Agent. I can let you have more info if this sounds like a solution to you!

Comment: I'm still not clear why you need to involve SSIS?

Comment: To see a tutorial of what alejandro is suggesting, try this: http://www.slideshare.net/KashikarR/automating-reports-with-ssrs-subscriptions

Comment: MiguelH - Sounds like a plan. What you suggest ?   Matt Gibson - In my report, I will accept a parameter. Let's say invoice number. After completing certain process, I can only trigger to generate this report. So, I am using SSIS to run a query to pass in the invoice number to the SSRS report. Other than using SSIS to pass in the parameter I want, I can't find any option to do it.   Daniel - I am using MSSQL 2008R2 Standard version, so Data Driven Subscription is not available.

Answer (score 2):

**SSIS controlling the running of an SSRS in SQL Agent.**
This assumes that the SSIS job will have updated a control record or written some other identifiable record to a database.
1. Create a subscription for the report.
2. Run this SQL to get the GUID of the report

```
 SELECT  c.Name AS ReportName
  , rs.ScheduleID AS JOB_NAME
  , s.[Description]
  , s.LastStatus
  , s.LastRunTime
FROM 
  ReportServer..[Catalog] c 
  JOIN ReportServer..Subscriptions s ON c.ItemID = s.Report_OID 
  JOIN ReportServer..ReportSchedule rs ON c.ItemID = rs.ReportID
  AND rs.SubscriptionID = s.SubscriptionID<br>
```

3. Create a SQL Agent job.
a. Step 1.
     A SQL statement to look for data in a table containing a flagged record where the Advanced setting is "on failure end job reporting success"

```
IF NOT exists ( select top 1 * from mytable where mykey = 'x' 
and mycondition = 'y') RAISERROR ('No Records Found',16,1)
```

b. Step 2

```
USE msdb 
EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = ‘1X2C91X5-8B86-4CDA-9G1B-112C4F6E450A'<br>
```

Replacing the GUID with the one returned from your GUID query.
One thing to note though ... once the report subscription has been executed then as far as SQL Agent is concerned then that step is complete, even though the report has not necessarily finished running. I once had a clean up job after the Exec step which effectively deleted some of my data before the report reached it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subscription for the report that is never scheduled to run.

If you have the Subscription ID, you can fire the report subscription using a simple SQL Task in SSIS.

You can get the Subscription ID from the Report Server database.  It is in the Subscriptions table.
Use this query to help locate the subscription:

```
SELECT Catalog.Path
      ,Catalog.Name
      ,SubscriptionID
      ,Subscriptions.Description

FROM Catalog
   
   INNER JOIN Subscriptions 
   ON Catalog.ItemID = Subscriptions.Report_OID
```

In SSIS, you can use this statement, inside of a SQL Task, to fire the subscription:

```
 EXEC reportserver.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription',@EventData=  [Your Subscription ID]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My SSRS report needs to accept user input, I guess more tricky than that. In the end, I do it using SSIS Script Task to call SSRS report.

Next would be scheduling it using SQL Server Agent to call the SSIS package.